# Number of trees with n nodes and m leaves

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Even searching for " ['number of trees' leaves](https://oeis.org/search?q=%22number+of+trees%22+leaves) " didn't reveal what I am looking for: an approach for calculating the (approximate) number of trees with exactly n nodes and m leaves. Any hints from MO?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to this (very natural) question depends on your notion of "tree" (e.g. free, rooted) and the equivalence relation you employ (e.g. labelled, unlabelled).  I haven't gone into the nitty-gritty details of all these results, but here's what I've found so far.  There's likely published results I haven't found yet, but hopefully this helps to get you started.

We can compute $T_{m,n}$, the number of non-isomorphic free trees with $m$ leaves and $n$ vertices, for small $m$ and large $m$.  For example, (a) $T_{3,n}$ is the number of partitions of $n-1$ into $3$ positive integer parts ([Sloane's A001399](https://oeis.org/A001399)), (b) $T_{n-2,n}=\lfloor (n-2)/2 \rfloor$ and (c) $T_{n-3,n}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-5} \lfloor (n-3-j)/2 \rfloor$.  The first result can be observed by deleting the vertex of degree 3 and the last two can be observed by colouring each non-leaf vertex by the number of adjacent leaves, then deleting the leaves.

Yu (8) seems to have given an algorithm for generating rooted trees with $m$ leaves.  Wang (6) and Liu (3,4) considered the number of "structurally different" trees with $m$ leaves (according to MathSciNet).  Bergeron, Labelle and Leroux (1) consider the expected number of leaves in trees that admit a certain automorphism.  Lam (2) discusses embeddings of trees with $m$ leaves and discusses trees with $(d+1)d^{r+1}$ leaves for integers d and r.

Wilf (7. p. 163) gave a generating function for $\sum_k T_{k,n}^{\text{lab}}$ where $T_{k,n}^{\text{lab}}$ is the number of labelled free trees with $m$ leaves and $n$ vertices.  He also gives a formula for the average number of leaves in a labelled tree with $n$ vertices.

There is also this:  K. Yamanaka, Y. Otachi, S.-I. Nakano [Efficient Enumeration of Ordered Trees with k Leaves](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-00202-1_13), which I haven't looked at yet.

(1) F. Bergeron, G. Labelle, and P. Leroux, [Computation of the expected number of leaves in a tree having a given automorphism, and related topics](https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X(91)90078-B), Discrete Appl. Math., 34 (1991), pp. 49-66.

(2) P. C. B. Lam, [On number of leaves and bandwidth of trees](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02677426), Acta Math. Appl. Sinica (English Ser.), 14 (1998), pp. 193-196.

(3) B. L. Liu, The enumeration of directed trees with a given number of leaves and the enumeration of free trees, Kexue Tongbao, 32 (1987), pp. 244-247. In Chinese.

(4) B. L. Liu, Enumeration of oriented trees and free trees with a given number of leaves, Kexue Tongbao (English Ed.), 33 (1988), pp. 1577-1581.

(5) Q. Q. Nong, The degree sequence and number of leaves in a tree, J. Yunnan Univ. Nat. Sci., 24 (2002), pp. 167-171. In Chinese.

(6) Z. Y. Wang, An enumeration problem on ordered trees, J. Math. (Wuhan), 6 (1986), pp. 201-208.

(7) H. C. Wilf, Generatingfunctionology, Academic Press, 1990.

(8) Q. L. Yu, An algorithm for lexicographically generating ordered rooted trees with constraints on the number of leaves, Chinese J. Oper. Res., 6 (1987), pp. 71-72

Answer (score 8):

I think this is what you want:

[OEIS: the triangle of trees with n nodes and k leaves](http://oeis.org/A055290)

(You should draw the sequence as a triangle as below to get the 2-dimensional information.)

```
                                            1                                           
                                        1       0                                       
                                    1       1       0                                   
                                1       1       1       0                               
                            1       2       2       1       0                           
                        1       3       4       2       1       0                       
                    1       4       8       6       3       1       0                   
                1       5       14      14      9       3       1       0               
            1       7       23      32      26      12      4       1       0           
        1       8       36      64      66      39      16      4       1       0       
    1       10      54      123     158     119     60      20      5       1       0   
1       12      78      219     350     325     202     83      25      5       1       0
```

Edit: I edited to use a different representation of the data. I assume that the n-th row, k-th entry means the number of trees with n nodes and k leaves. See [these other displays](http://oeis.org/A055290/table)

Comment: I stumbled over this already, but couldn't make sense of the title: "the TRIANGLE of n nodes and k leaves". And the only reference - Harary's 'Graphical Enumeration' - is almost invisible at books.google.com. Are you sure?

Comment: The OEIS is just for (one dimensional) sequences, but this is a two-dimensional function, having two arguments. So they organize it in a triangle.

Comment: I edited it to use a clearer representation of the data.

Comment: To maybe save others some confusion: The top row is n=2, and the leftmost column is k=2.

Comment: @Joel: Sorry for not accepting your answer, but I am looking for the "idea" of counting those trees, not for the results only.


Comment: No problem, Hans, I know what you mean. I guess one way is to track down that reference.

Comment: Is there a rule to compute each entry from the two entries above as in Pascal's triangle?

Answer (score 5):

The number of labelled trees on $n$ vertices with $m$ leaves is 
$$\binom{n}{m}S(n-2,n-m)(n-m)!$$
where $S(a,b)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind. This can be seen by analysing the multivariate generation which counts trees of any degree sequence given here: https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/matrixtree.pdf